# How to get data from POST request in Django

Tags: django

I spent a lot of time trying to get data from POST request in my django 1.8 application and it doesn't work whatever I do. Hopping that somebody more skillful suggest the solution.

I need to get data from the request:

```
curl.exe -X POST --data "Status=OK"  http://localhost:8000/postback
```

relevant content of urls.py :

```
url(r'^postback', 'app.views.process_postback'),
```

relevant content of views.py :

```
@csrf_exempt
def process_postback(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dict = request.POST
        print(dict)

    return HttpResponse("OK")
```

I always get empty value in dict : 
My question how to get Status from post to inside my app

Here is few more details:

1. I process postbacks from third party website, so I cannot change content of POST request
2. I don't need(want) any forms/models for the request, I just need to collect value of Status.

Thanks for help.

Comment: instead of dict = request.POST, can you try status = request.POST.get('status')

Comment: What does `print(request.body)` show?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I tried status = request.POST.get('status'), after that line executed status equal None.

Comment: I also tried print(request.body) and got exception:   File "C:\work\django\postback\postback\env\lib\site-packages\django\http\reque
st.py", line 231, in body
    raise RawPostDataException("You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream")
django.http.request.RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out what's was wrong. I use VS 2013 with PTVS (Python Tool for Visual Studio) as my development environment. And it appears that if project launched under debugger then http request gets screwed up. If I run project without debugger then everything works fine. I tried to look at the debugger code (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_debugger.py) but didn't find some obvious things that would cause such behavior. If anybody came across it and knows how to fix it would be great to know.

Comment: This occurs when using VS Code as well, debugging a Django app. The VS Code debugger strips out the POST parameters for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Following the https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Remove `-X POST` option from Your command

```
curl.exe --data "Status=OK"  http://localhost:8000/postback
```

Output:

```
<QueryDict: {u'Status': [u'OK']}>
[04/Dec/2015 21:03:15] "POST /postback HTTP/1.1" 200 2
```

`pip freeze` output:

```
Django==1.8.6
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I know -X POST is kinda redundant, if there is data option present then curl treats request as POST anyway. I removed -X option and result is the same: inside process_postback()  request has empty QueryDict, no status info.

Comment: You probably have problem in other place.

Comment: You're probably right, I have problem somewhere, just couldn't figure out where. I upgraded django to 1.8.6 but still not getting status. Tomasz I see everything works fine on your site. Could you please send me you project? If your code runs on my machine then I'll be able to figure out where the problem is.  Hope I am not asking too much. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much Tomasz, it works. I guess I need to start from bare bone project trying to add stuff until breaks. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I used django 1.10.so i only can give some advice.when i want to get the value from the form ,no matter GET or POST,i used`dict=request.POST.get('dict')`
The second 'dict' is your form's input name .Such as in html , it's should be `

```
<form name="input" method="post">

   <input type="text" name="dict" >

   <input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>`
```